# How to import messy data in R?

Tags: r, import, data-cleaning

How to import this data in R ???is so messy...I dont know if must first cleaning and then import..i dont know what to do....in the first line is the names of columns.

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/

[image: sample data]

Comment: this work ..thanks ..but when i run names(df)    [1] "\"fixed acidity"              "\"\"volatile acidity\"\""    
 [3] "\"\"citric acid\"\""          "\"\"residual sugar\"\""      
 [5] "\"\"chlorides\"\""            "\"\"free sulfur dioxide\"\"" 
 [7] "\"\"total sulfur dioxide\"\"" "\"\"density\"\""             
 [9] "\"\"pH\"\""                   "\"\"sulphates\"\""           
[11] "\"\"alcohol\"\""              "\"\"quality\"\"\""

Answer (score 3):

It is not messy but very clean. The file is a comma separated values file (although the delimiter seems to be a semi-colon). You can use read.delim for this:

```
df <- read.delim("winequality-red.csv", sep = ";")
```

Make sure that the file is stored in the working directory. You can check the working directory by using `getwd()` and change it by `setwd()`

Comment: Thanks..i understand what you said but dont run(the file is in the right directory)

Comment: share your code so that error can be identified. Also did you change your working directory?

Comment: a <- read.delim("wine.csv",sep = ";")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names

Comment: a
, , 1

     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "red"   "black"
[2,] "black" "red"  
[3,] "red"   "black"

, , 2

     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "red"   "black"
[2,] "black" "red"  
[3,] "red"   "black"

Comment: are you trying to import the file which is shown in the image above or some other file. If other, then please share a screenshot of that file

Comment: Download the file again and don't open it in excel. Directly import in R. It is working fine on my machine

Comment: dont run...thanks  the solution tell me Ryan is this: